# unable to assign array value to variable

Tags: php, laravel, react-native

i am developing a react native app and i do post product id in body with json stringify but in backend laravel i am unable to search database record with those product id ..here is my code for react native.product id declare as array in state

```
onPlaceOrder=async ()=>{
console.log(this.state.product_id)
    var userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken");
    fetch('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/tajroof/public/api/createSales', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization:`Bearer ${userToken}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(
           this.state.product_id

        )

        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

            console.log(responseJson)
                // Alert.alert(responseJson.status);
                // this.setState({modalVisible:false})

        }).catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
        });

   }
```

here is my laravel controller code

```
$myid=$request->all();


$length = count($myid);

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  echo $myid[$i];
}
```

here my product id are 2 and 5 and i first got response array[2,5,]in console and after for loop i got 25.so how it possible to search db record with that two different ids.
please help with code..your help will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_findMany), Eloquent allows you to get elements from your database passing to `findMany` and array of ids (that will match the primary key).
So let's say you have a model `Post`, you will have to do this:

```
$posts = Post::findMany($myid);
```

Note: works fine also `Post::find($myid)`

Comment: @RoboRobok yes sure, infact here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php you can see that it checks if it's an array, and if it is, it calls findMany, but i'll add it as note

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses the `find()` method of a model to return a model matching the primary key(s). Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections#method-find)
e.g

```
$myid=$request->all();
$product = Product::find($myid);
```

Comment: my problem is i have two seperate id 2 and 5 and after for loop i got as 25..how to extract 2 and 5 separately and assign to variable and search db record

Comment: i got response from react native side like Array[2,5,] and after for loop in laravel i got 25..now how can i assign id 2 and 5 in product search